# Calculate the difference between two dates in salesforce

Tags: apex, trigger

```
public class trigger36 {
    public static void trigger1(List<Account> accList)
    {
        Set<id> accId = new Set<id>();
        List<Account> Listoppos = new List<Account>();
        Map<id,List<Opportunity>> MapacOp = new Map<id,List<Opportunity>>();
        List<Opportunity> updated = new List<Opportunity>();
     
        for(Account a : accList)
        {
            accId.add(a.id);// fetch id of all accounts which were updated
        }

        Listoppos =  [select Id, (Select name,StageName,CreatedDate from Opportunities) from Account where ID IN: accId]; 
        for(Account a :Listoppos)
        {
            MapacOp.put(a.id, a.opportunities);
        }

        for(Id i: accId)
        {
            List<Opportunity> x = MapacOp.get(i);
            for(opportunity xx:x)
            { 
                if(xx.StageName != 'ClosedWon' &&  System.Today() -  30 > xx.CreatedDate.date())
                {
                    xx.StageName ='Closed Lost';
                    updated.add(xx);
                }
            }
            if(updated.size() > 0)
            {
                update updated;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am trying to write a trigger which changes the opportunity StageName as per the conditions:
Update all Opportunities Stage to close lost if an opportunity created date is greater than 30 days from today and stage not equal to close won.

My code seems to be working fine but I wish to understand why
`System.Today() -  30 > xx.CreatedDate.date()` seems to be working fine but
`System.Today() - xx.CreatedDate.date() > 30` seems to fire an error,

> Date expressions must use Integer or Long

What exactly is this error trying to imply?

PS. xx is an `Opportunity` object and x is `list<Opportunity>`.

Answer (score 2):

It's simply saying you can't add/subtract two dates. The `-` and `+` operators are [overloaded](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operator_overloading) on `Date` to call the `addDays` function with the `Integer`/`Long` as the parameter, and returns a date that results from that method.

If you really wanted the time between two dates, you'd have to convert them to `DateTime` values, then use the `getTime` method to count the number of milliseconds between the two, and finally divide by 86400000 to get the number of days.

So, logistically speaking, it's much easier to use `addDays` to adjust one of the dates, and then compare the resulting value. Alternatively, you can use the `daysBetween` method if you wanted that comparison to read a bit clearer:

```
if(xx.CreatedDate.date().daysBetween(Date.Today()) > 30) {
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer @sfdcfox, clear and crisp. I assumed apex would allow use of +,- on dates just like formulas do.

Comment: @codedeveloper That's not an unfair assumption, especially if you start from formulas then move to Apex. I came from the other direction (Java, ScriptScript, etc), so I wasn't entirely surprised it didn't support it. That actually would be a pretty nifty [Idea](https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/search) that I could get behind.

Comment: Thanks again for the clarification. :)